# "return codecs.charmap_encode" when running python script with no unusual characters

Tags: python, windows, encoding, cmd, python-idle

I'm trying to run my script in CMD (it works fine in IDLE), but I get this error:

`C:\Python34>rule90.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\rule90.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(c)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-39: character maps to <undefined>`

and although I have limited experience with python, I thought I'd know enough to work this one out. Line 19 is simply `linenew = str(''.join(lineA[numberneg:numberpos]))`, and lineA which I'm joining comprises of a load of '0's and a '1', in string form. I do have ■ and □ characters, but they should be default characters in cmd, and the error isn't on that line anyway.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
lineA = ['0','0','0','0','0','0','1','0','0','0','0','0','0']
lineB = lineA[:]
lineC = lineA[:]
lineC = ['□' if x=='0' else '■' for x in lineC]
counth = 0
max_counth = len(lineA) - 2
countv = 0
max_countv = len(lineA) / 2 - 1

while countv < max_countv:
    number = 1
    counth = 0
    lineCstr = map(str, lineC)    
    c = ''.join(lineCstr)
    print(c)
    while counth < max_counth:
        numberneg = number - 1
        numberpos = number + 2
        linenew = str(''.join(lineA[numberneg:numberpos]))
        if linenew == str('110') or linenew == str('100') or linenew == str('011') or linenew == str('001'):
            lineB[number] = '1'
            lineC[number] = '■'
        else:
            lineB[number] = '0'
            lineC[number] = '□'
        number = number + 1
        counth = counth + 1

    lineA = lineB[:]
    countv = countv + 1
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

`lineA` is usually a longer list (25+ numbers), but for the sake of saving space I shortened it.

Comment: Please, post full code of your script.

Answer (score 0):

I can make one assumption. Currently, both symbols '□' and '■'- symbols of Unicode. You can get it's hex code like this:

```
import binascii
print (binascii.hexlify(bytes('□','UTF-8'))) #b'e296a1'
print (binascii.hexlify(bytes('■','UTF-8'))) #b'e296a0'
```

You can find Unicode table [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm?start=8121).
For some reason your console can not display Unicode characters. But you can find their equivalents in the console encoding:

```
for i in range(256):
    print (i,chr(i))
```

Remember the value of `i` for each square. Then you can do so:

```
BLACK_SQUARE = ord(some_integer_value)
WHITE_SQUARE = ord(some_integer_value)

lineC = [WHITE_SQUARE if x=='0' else BLACK_SQUARE  for x in lineC]
```